# Exchange Disclaimer plain text formatting

Tags: email, exchange-server

I am using a Transport Rule in Exchange Server 2010 to append some HTML to the end of our company emails. This is working just fine when an email is sent out as HTML. When the message is plain text, the HTML and images are converted into [links] and it looks a mess.

Is it possible to apply conditional formatting to append an HTML message at the end of HTML emails, and a different layout for plain text emails? Failing that, can I get it to simply ignore the rule if the message isn't in HTML?

Thank you

Comment: I've done a test trying to use the header match "regular expression". I checked "Content-Type" for "text-html" and that worked when sending from Thunderbird, but not Mac Mail / Outlook. Thunderbird seems to sent text/html or text/plain, and Mac Mail/Outlook have multipart/alternative. The regex seems to be some sort of crippled version so I don't think I can use any fancy rules.  Would really appreciate some input on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the only way to achieve what I was after is by using a 3rd party add-on. So the answer to the question really is "no" for both parts!

3rd party tools like [Symprex](http://www.symprex.com) or [Exclaimer](http://www.exclaimer.com) may help people out in a similar situation.